# Javascript Removing Formatting from mySQL Seperator

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

I added a script to my page to trim and add the show more link for anything over 100 char.  After I added this my text is no longer breaking on new results from notes.  Im trying to make this clear.

In my query, I am Left Joining and group_concat on note.   This will grab any note in the DB and group them together with a separator of

.

```
GROUP_CONCAT(n.note, " - (Contacted By: ", n.user, ")" ORDER BY n.note_id separator "<p></p>") as all_notes
```

Then in my javascript I have this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var maxLength = 100;
    $(".show-read-more").each(function(){
        var myStr = $(this).text();
        if($.trim(myStr).length > maxLength){
            var newStr = myStr.substring(0, maxLength);
            var removedStr = myStr.substring(maxLength, $.trim(myStr).length);
            $(this).empty().html(newStr);
            $(this).append(' <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="read-more">Read More...</a>');
            $(this).append('<span class="more-text">' + removedStr + '</span>');
        }
    });
    $(".read-more").click(function(){
        $(this).siblings(".more-text").contents().unwrap();
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
</script>
<style>
```

So this will break anything over 100 characters and add the Read More...  The issue is that if I have 2 note records for this row it just adds them all together.

```
03/20/2020 03:23: Called and left voicemail - (Contacted By: )03/20/2020 01:37: Unlimited $45 plus l oyalty 2 lines, could save $10/mo with autopay. - (Contacted By: Nate)
```

**It should be like this**

```
03/20/2020 03:23: Called and left a voicemail - (Contacted By Jake )
03/20/2020 01:37: Unlimited $45 plus loyalty 2 lines, could save $10/mo with autopay. - (Contacted By: Nate)
```

**Here is my TD**

```
 echo "<td class='notes show-read-more'>" . $notes. "</td>";
```

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this with the current setup?  I tried removing the span in the javascript and adding `<p>` but that did not work.  I also attempted to change my sql statement to have `<br />` but this also was not working.  Adding into the JS `$(this).prepend('<br />');` also did nothing.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use "\n" to break a line.

```
GROUP_CONCAT(n.note, " - (Contacted By: ", n.user, ")" ORDER BY n.note_id separator "\n") as all_notes
```

OR

```
GROUP_CONCAT("<p>", n.note, " - (Contacted By: ", n.user, ")" ORDER BY n.note_id separator "</p>") as all_notes
```

Comment: This still has the same behavior. although I did change that in my code for future.  \n is better in this case.